# Python Configparser. Whitespace causes AttributeError

Tags: python, attributeerror, configparser

I recieve some files with .ini file with them. I have to recieve file names from [FILES] section.
Sometimes there is an extra witespace in another section of .ini-file which raises exception in ConfigParser module
The example of "bad" ini-file:

```
[LETTER]
SUBJECT=some text
some text
 and text with whitespace in the beggining 

[FILES]
0=file1.txt
1=file2.doc
```

My code(Python 3.7):

```
import configparser

def get_files_from_ini_file(info_file):
    ini = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    ini.read(info_file) # ERROR is here
    if ini.has_section("FILES"):
        pocket_files = [ini.get("FILES", i) for i in ini.options("FILES")]
        return pocket_files

print(get_files_from_ini_file("D:\\bad.ini"))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(get_files_from_ini_file("D:\\bad.ini"))
  File "D:/test.py", line 5, in get_files_from_ini_file
    ini.read(info_file) # ERROR
  File "C:\Users\ap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\ap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\configparser.py", line 1054, in _read
    cursect[optname].append(value)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I can't influence on files I recieve so that is there any way to ignore this error? In fact I need only [FILES] section to parse. 
Have tried empty_lines_in_values=False with no result
May be that's invalid ini file and I should write my own parser?

Comment: It's not like there was ever a specification for INI files.  Interpretation is up to the user.

Comment: The problem is that the line following `SUBJECT` doesn't start with a space; you could pre-parse the file and add a space in those instances, but it wouldn't be easy to decide when a space would be needed - at that point you're better off just getting what you need yourself, as the configuration isn't valid to begin with.

Comment: @Grismar got it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the "FILES" part, a simple way is to:

- open the file and read into a string
- get the part after "[FILES]" using .split() method
- add "[FILES]" before the string
- use the configparser **read_string** method on the string

This is a hacky solution but it should work:

```
  import configparser

  def get_files_from_ini_file(info_file):
      with open(info_file, 'r') as file:
          ini_string = file.read()
      useful_part = "[FILES]" + ini_string.split("[FILES]")[-1]

      ini = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
      ini.read_string(useful_part) # ERROR is here
      if ini.has_section("FILES"):
          pocket_files = [ini.get("FILES", i) for i in ini.options("FILES")]
          return pocket_files

  print(get_files_from_ini_file("D:\\bad.ini"))
```

Comment: appreciate your help